# D3 axis label has to be added separately?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

In [this axis label example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/23e42c8f67210ac6c678db2cd07a747e), which uses D3 v4, it adds the x axis and the text label as separate nodes under svg.

```
  // Add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")             
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                           (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Date");
```

When I chain the code above (hence moving the text element under the x axis group):

```
  // Add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .append("text")             
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Date");
```

Then my axis title is not visible any more (see screenshot below). I can still find my text element in DOM, under the x axis group, but it's not there in the rendered HTML.

[image]

I want to know:

1. Is it by design that D3 wants me to add axis and its label separately (i.e., not chaining)?
2. Why is my text element not visible after I move it under the x axis group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> D3 axis label has to be added separately?

No, it doesn't. You **can** chain, that's not the problem. The problem here is the `fill` of the text element.

As you can see in the screenshot you linked, the container group has "none" as `fill`. Since the text inherits the parent's attributes/styles, you'll have to change its `fill` from "none" to any color you want:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, 10])
    .range([10,390]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr("transform","translate(0,40)")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "black")//set the fill here
    .attr("transform","translate(120, 40)")
    .text("Hello World!!!");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="80"></svg>
```

PS: this problem wouldn't happen in D3 v3.x.